# how to configure jekyll with netlify cms to edit & create pages

Tags: jekyll, netlify-cms

I have a simple jekyll site and am trying to get netlify cms to work as the editor for the pages aswell as the posts.

If I tryt o move the pages into a pages folder in the the custom collections folder then it doesn't seem to build them unless they have an .md extension but the pages have plenty fo custom html in them and using .md appears to render the html on the page as text not html.

If I leave the pages in the root then netlify cms doesn't pick them up however I configure it.

There are 3 main kinds of page, Home page, a second level gateway type page, content pages

and then blog posts.

How should I configure this so that netlify can edit my pages and users can create new pages?

Site is here:
https://github.com/tofuwarrior/sites-clearspringacupuncture

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Netlify CMS is a great system. However, if you want a WordPress-like experience that is also very forgiving for the developer, I recommend CloudCannon. This is a paid CMS, but it supports visual editing, which means any static page with `<div class='editable'></div>` can be edited within their system. It also supports image resizing. Creating new pages in CloudCannon is as simple as cloning old ones and renaming them. It is absolutely worth checking out.

Back to your question... It seems like you wrote 'page' instead of 'pages' in your config.yml file. Here is [a working config file](https://gist.github.com/maciejmatu/987563ede550e7b9f1644cd01882e6f5) for Netlify, in which you can see that the correct name is 'pages'.

PS. I noticed you have a 'customcollections' folder. This seems odd to me. Aren't all collections custom collections in Jekyll?